# Thunderbird won't connect to Dovecot server

Tags: ssl, dovecot, thunderbird

Since yesterday my Thunderbird client can't connect to my mail server but two other clients I tried have no problem to retrieve email.

In my mail log file I have these lines:

```
Nov 26 13:24:46 LinuxWebServer dovecot: imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate: SSL alert number 42
Nov 26 13:24:46 LinuxWebServer dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=*.*.*.*, lip=*.*.*.*, TLS: SSL_read() failed: Unknown error, session=<MGGQqAa1aMhFRiQi>
Nov 26 13:24:51 LinuxWebServer dovecot: imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate: SSL alert number 42
Nov 26 13:24:51 LinuxWebServer dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=*.*.*.*, lip=*.*.*.*, TLS: SSL_read() failed: Unknown error, session=<W7viqAa1achFRiQi>
```

I have checked the validity of my certificate and it's still valid up to 2027.

With Sylpheed mail client I get the following dialog:

```
The SSL certificate of mail.somedomain.com cannot be verified by the following reason:
  unable to get local issuer certificate

Subject: /CN=LinuxWebServer
Issuer: /OU=generated by Avast Antivirus for self-signed certificates/O=Avast Web/Mail Shield/CN=Avast Web/Mail Shield Self-signed Root
Issued date: Feb  9 20:02:57 2017 GMT
Expire date: Feb  7 20:02:57 2027 GMT

SHA1 fingerprint: 70:0C:A4:FA:25:11:1F:2B:27:A8:66:99:89:11:A7:21:04:26:52:54
MD5 fingerprint: 45:0E:2B:CF:FA:AD:7C:D6:A8:18:DE:2C:36:B8:FA:20
```

I understands there is a clue about the issue in this warning but I just don't really understand what it technically mean

EDIT:

In 10-ssl.conf:

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ameloracerts/mailsrvs.ca.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ameloracerts/mailsrvs.key
```

In 99-mail-stack-delivery.conf:

```
99-mail-stack-delivery.conf
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_cipher_list = 
ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
```

Comment: Could you add the TLS-configuration parameters from your Dovecot. Otherwise this might well be a client-side issue and a bit off-topic on Serverfault. We have to rule this out. I do have some good general advice on this, which may not directly answer your question, but will improve your security. Currently I have some paid work to do, first.

Comment: `Issuer: /OU=generated by Avast Antivirus for self-signed certificates/O=Avast Web/Mail Shield` ... my guess would be that the Avast Antivirus installed on your local machine is intercepting the connection to your mail server. Your Thunderbird needs to trust this certificate if you want to keep using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more investigation I found that I was using two different certificates (one self-signed and one paid) and one of them was expired.

I bought a new certificate and configured it in **10-ssl.conf** then I removed the SSL configuration in **99-mail-stack-delivery.conf** that was apparently the main cause of the issue.

My mail server now works as expected.

Thanks to **Esa Jokinen** who put me on the right track to find the solution.